# Issue with VkRenderPass load operation for Skybox rendering

Tags: intel, nvidia, vulkan

I seem to have another issue when it comes to renderpasses in Vulkan.

Drawing my scene, I first submit a commandbuffer to render a sky using atmospheric scattering onto a cubemap, to which I then use for my forward pass to draw out the sky and sun.

The renderpass used when drawing the skybox and storing into a cubemap for sampling:

```
  m_pFrameBuffer = rhi->CreateFrameBuffer();
  VkImageView attachment = m_RenderTexture->View();

  VkAttachmentDescription attachDesc = CreateAttachmentDescription(
    m_RenderTexture->Format(),
    VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED,
    VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL,
    VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_CLEAR,
    VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_STORE,
    VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_DONT_CARE,
    VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_DONT_CARE,
    m_RenderTexture->Samples()
  );

  VkAttachmentReference colorRef = { 0, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL };

  std::array<VkSubpassDependency, 2> dependencies;
  dependencies[0] = CreateSubPassDependency(
    VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL,
    VK_ACCESS_MEMORY_READ_BIT,
    VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_BOTTOM_OF_PIPE_BIT,
    0,
    VK_ACCESS_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_READ_BIT | VK_ACCESS_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_WRITE_BIT,
    VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT,
    VK_DEPENDENCY_BY_REGION_BIT
  );

  dependencies[1] = CreateSubPassDependency(
    0,
    VK_ACCESS_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_READ_BIT | VK_ACCESS_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_WRITE_BIT,
    VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT,
    VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL,
    VK_ACCESS_MEMORY_READ_BIT,
    VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_BOTTOM_OF_PIPE_BIT,
    VK_DEPENDENCY_BY_REGION_BIT
  );

  VkSubpassDescription subpassDesc = { };
  subpassDesc.colorAttachmentCount = 1;
  subpassDesc.pColorAttachments = &colorRef;
  subpassDesc.pipelineBindPoint = VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS;

  VkRenderPassCreateInfo renderpassCi = { };
  renderpassCi.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_RENDER_PASS_CREATE_INFO;
  renderpassCi.attachmentCount = 1;
  renderpassCi.pAttachments = &attachDesc;
  renderpassCi.dependencyCount = static_cast<u32>(dependencies.size());
  renderpassCi.pDependencies = dependencies.data();
  renderpassCi.subpassCount = 1;
  renderpassCi.pSubpasses = &subpassDesc;

  VkFramebufferCreateInfo framebufferCi = { };
  framebufferCi.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_FRAMEBUFFER_CREATE_INFO;
  framebufferCi.height = kTextureSize;
  framebufferCi.width = kTextureSize;
  framebufferCi.attachmentCount = 1;
  framebufferCi.layers = 1;
  framebufferCi.pAttachments = &attachment;

  m_pFrameBuffer->Finalize(framebufferCi, renderpassCi);
```

After rendering the skybox, and storing it into a cubemap, I used the following renderpass to sample the sky onto the rendered scene. This pass uses VK_LOAD_OP_LOAD so as to not clear the rendered scene when drawing the skybox onto it:

```
  // Create a renderpass for the pbr overlay.
  Texture* pbrColor = gResources().GetRenderTexture(PBRColorAttachStr);
  Texture* pbrNormal = gResources().GetRenderTexture(PBRNormalAttachStr);
  Texture* pbrPosition = gResources().GetRenderTexture(PBRPositionAttachStr);
  Texture* pbrRoughMetal = gResources().GetRenderTexture(PBRRoughMetalAttachStr);
  Texture* pbrDepth = gResources().GetRenderTexture(PBRDepthAttachStr);
  Texture* RTBright = gResources().GetRenderTexture(RenderTargetBrightStr);

  std::array<VkAttachmentDescription, 6> attachmentDescriptions;
  VkSubpassDependency dependenciesNative[2];

  attachmentDescriptions[0] = CreateAttachmentDescription(
    pbrColor->Format(),
    VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED,
    VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL,
    VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_LOAD,
    VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_STORE,
    VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_DONT_CARE,
    VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_DONT_CARE,
    pbrColor->Samples()
  );

  attachmentDescriptions[1] = CreateAttachmentDescription(
    pbrNormal->Format(),
    VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED,
    VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL,
    VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_LOAD,
    VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_STORE,
    VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_DONT_CARE,
    VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_DONT_CARE,
    pbrNormal->Samples()
  );

  attachmentDescriptions[2] = CreateAttachmentDescription(
    RTBright->Format(),
    VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED,
    VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL,
    VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_LOAD,
    VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_STORE,
    VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_DONT_CARE,
    VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_DONT_CARE,
    RTBright->Samples()
  );

  attachmentDescriptions[3] = CreateAttachmentDescription(
    pbrPosition->Format(),
    VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED,
    VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL,
    VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_LOAD,
    VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_STORE,
    VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_DONT_CARE,
    VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_DONT_CARE,
    pbrPosition->Samples()
  );

  attachmentDescriptions[4] = CreateAttachmentDescription(
    pbrRoughMetal->Format(),
    VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED,
    VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL,
    VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_LOAD,
    VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_STORE,
    VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_DONT_CARE,
    VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_DONT_CARE,
    pbrRoughMetal->Samples()
  );

  attachmentDescriptions[5] = CreateAttachmentDescription(
    pbrDepth->Format(),
    VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED,
    VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL,
    VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_LOAD,
    VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_STORE,
    VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_DONT_CARE,
    VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_DONT_CARE,
    pbrDepth->Samples()
  );

  dependenciesNative[0] = CreateSubPassDependency(
    VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL,
    VK_ACCESS_MEMORY_READ_BIT,
    VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_BOTTOM_OF_PIPE_BIT,
    0,
    VK_ACCESS_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_READ_BIT | VK_ACCESS_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_WRITE_BIT,
    VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT,
    VK_DEPENDENCY_BY_REGION_BIT
  );

  dependenciesNative[1] = CreateSubPassDependency(
    0,
    VK_ACCESS_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_READ_BIT | VK_ACCESS_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_WRITE_BIT,
    VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT,
    VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL,
    VK_ACCESS_MEMORY_READ_BIT,
    VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_BOTTOM_OF_PIPE_BIT,
    VK_DEPENDENCY_BY_REGION_BIT
  );

  std::array<VkAttachmentReference, 5> attachmentColors;
  VkAttachmentReference attachmentDepthRef = { static_cast<u32>(attachmentColors.size()), VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL };
  attachmentColors[0].attachment = 0;
  attachmentColors[0].layout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL;

  attachmentColors[1].attachment = 1;
  attachmentColors[1].layout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL;

  attachmentColors[2].attachment = 2;
  attachmentColors[2].layout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL;

  attachmentColors[3].attachment = 3;
  attachmentColors[3].layout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL;

  attachmentColors[4].attachment = 4;
  attachmentColors[4].layout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL;

  VkSubpassDescription subpass = {};
  subpass.pipelineBindPoint = VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS;
  subpass.colorAttachmentCount = static_cast<u32>(attachmentColors.size());
  subpass.pColorAttachments = attachmentColors.data();
  subpass.pDepthStencilAttachment = &attachmentDepthRef;

  VkRenderPassCreateInfo renderpassCI = CreateRenderPassInfo(
    static_cast<u32>(attachmentDescriptions.size()),
    attachmentDescriptions.data(),
    2,
    dependenciesNative,
    1,
    &subpass
  );

  VkResult result = 
    vkCreateRenderPass(rhi->LogicDevice()->Native(), &renderpassCI, nullptr, &m_SkyboxRenderPass);
```

This is the command buffer for rendering the sky onto my scene. I submit this commandbuffer after rendering the scene to take advantage of early z rejection:

```
  if (m_pSkyboxCmdBuffer) {
    m_pRhi->DeviceWaitIdle();
    m_pSkyboxCmdBuffer->Reset(VK_COMMAND_BUFFER_RESET_RELEASE_RESOURCES_BIT);
  }

  VkCommandBufferBeginInfo beginInfo = { };
  beginInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_COMMAND_BUFFER_BEGIN_INFO;

  CommandBuffer* buf = m_pSkyboxCmdBuffer;
  FrameBuffer* skyFrameBuffer = gResources().GetFrameBuffer(PBRFrameBufferStr);
  GraphicsPipeline* skyPipeline = gResources().GetGraphicsPipeline(SkyboxPipelineStr);
  DescriptorSet* global = m_pGlobal->Set();
  DescriptorSet* skybox = gResources().GetDescriptorSet(SkyboxDescriptorSetStr);

  VkDescriptorSet descriptorSets[] = {
    global->Handle(),
    skybox->Handle()
  };  

  buf->Begin(beginInfo);
    std::array<VkClearValue, 6> clearValues;
    clearValues[0].color = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
    clearValues[1].color = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
    clearValues[2].color = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
    clearValues[3].color = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
    clearValues[4].color = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
    clearValues[5].depthStencil = { 1.0f, 0 };

    VkViewport viewport = {};
    viewport.height = (r32)m_pWindow->Height();
    viewport.width = (r32)m_pWindow->Width();
    viewport.minDepth = 0.0f;
    viewport.maxDepth = 1.0f;
    viewport.y = 0.0f;
    viewport.x = 0.0f;

    VkRenderPassBeginInfo renderBegin = { };
    renderBegin.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_RENDER_PASS_BEGIN_INFO;
    renderBegin.framebuffer = skyFrameBuffer->Handle();
    renderBegin.renderPass = m_pSky->GetSkyboxRenderPass();
    renderBegin.clearValueCount = static_cast<u32>(clearValues.size());
    renderBegin.pClearValues = clearValues.data();
    renderBegin.renderArea.offset = { 0, 0 };
    renderBegin.renderArea.extent = m_pRhi->SwapchainObject()->SwapchainExtent();

    // Start the renderpass.
    buf->BeginRenderPass(renderBegin, VK_SUBPASS_CONTENTS_INLINE);
      buf->SetViewPorts(0, 1, &viewport);
      buf->BindPipeline(VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS, skyPipeline->Pipeline());
      buf->BindDescriptorSets(VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS, skyPipeline->Layout(), 0, 2, descriptorSets, 0, nullptr);
      VertexBuffer* vertexbuffer = m_pSky->GetSkyboxVertexBuffer();
      IndexBuffer* idxBuffer = m_pSky->GetSkyboxIndexBuffer();

      VkDeviceSize offsets[] =  { 0 };
      VkBuffer vert = vertexbuffer->Handle()->NativeBuffer();
      VkBuffer ind = idxBuffer->Handle()->NativeBuffer();
      buf->BindVertexBuffers(0 , 1, &vert, offsets);  
      buf->BindIndexBuffer(ind, 0, VK_INDEX_TYPE_UINT32);
      buf->DrawIndexed(idxBuffer->IndexCount(), 1, 0, 0, 0);
    buf->EndRenderPass();
  buf->End();
```

Finally, I submit it inside my rendering function:

```
  // TODO(): Need to clean this up.
  VkCommandBuffer offscreenCmd = m_Offscreen._CmdBuffers[m_Offscreen._CurrCmdBufferIndex]->Handle();
  VkCommandBuffer skyBuffers[] = { m_Offscreen._CmdBuffers[m_Offscreen._CurrCmdBufferIndex]->Handle(), m_pSky->CmdBuffer()->Handle() };
  VkSemaphore skyWaits[] = { m_Offscreen._Semaphore->Handle(), m_pSky->SignalSemaphore()->Handle() };
  VkSemaphore waitSemas[] = { m_pRhi->SwapchainObject()->ImageAvailableSemaphore() };
  VkSemaphore signalSemas[] = { m_Offscreen._Semaphore->Handle() };
  VkSemaphore shadowSignal[] = { m_Offscreen._ShadowSema->Handle() };
  VkPipelineStageFlags waitFlags[] = { VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT, VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_ALL_COMMANDS_BIT };

  VkSubmitInfo offscreenSI = {};
  offscreenSI.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_SUBMIT_INFO;
  offscreenSI.pCommandBuffers = &offscreenCmd;
  offscreenSI.commandBufferCount = 1;
  offscreenSI.signalSemaphoreCount = 1;
  offscreenSI.pSignalSemaphores = signalSemas;
  offscreenSI.waitSemaphoreCount = 1;
  offscreenSI.pWaitSemaphores = waitSemas;
  offscreenSI.pWaitDstStageMask = waitFlags;

  VkSubmitInfo skyboxSI = offscreenSI;
  VkSemaphore skyboxWaits[] = { m_Offscreen._Semaphore->Handle() };
  VkSemaphore skyboxSignal[] = { m_SkyboxFinished->Handle() };
  VkCommandBuffer skyboxCmd = m_pSkyboxCmdBuffer->Handle();
  skyboxSI.commandBufferCount = 1;
  skyboxSI.pCommandBuffers = &skyboxCmd;
  skyboxSI.pSignalSemaphores = skyboxSignal;
  skyboxSI.pWaitSemaphores = skyboxWaits;

  VkSubmitInfo hdrSI = offscreenSI;
  VkSemaphore hdrWaits[] = { m_SkyboxFinished->Handle() };
  VkSemaphore hdrSignal[] = { m_HDR._Semaphore->Handle() };
  VkCommandBuffer hdrCmd = m_HDR._CmdBuffers[m_HDR._CurrCmdBufferIndex]->Handle();
  hdrSI.pCommandBuffers = &hdrCmd;
  hdrSI.pSignalSemaphores = hdrSignal;
  hdrSI.pWaitSemaphores = hdrWaits;

  VkSemaphore waitSemaphores = m_HDR._Semaphore->Handle();
  if (!m_HDR._Enabled) waitSemaphores = m_Offscreen._Semaphore->Handle();

  // Update materials before rendering the frame.
  UpdateMaterials();

  // begin frame. This is where we start our render process per frame.
  BeginFrame();
    while (m_Offscreen._CmdBuffers[m_HDR._CurrCmdBufferIndex]->Recording() || !m_pRhi->CmdBuffersComplete()) {}

    // Render shadow map here. Primary shadow map is our concern.
    if (m_pLights->PrimaryShadowEnabled()) {
      VkCommandBuffer shadowbuf[] = { m_Offscreen._ShadowCmdBuffers[m_Offscreen._CurrCmdBufferIndex]->Handle() };

      VkSubmitInfo shadowSubmit = { };
      shadowSubmit.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_SUBMIT_INFO;
      shadowSubmit.pCommandBuffers = shadowbuf;
      shadowSubmit.commandBufferCount = 1;
      shadowSubmit.signalSemaphoreCount = 1;
      shadowSubmit.waitSemaphoreCount = 1;
      shadowSubmit.pWaitSemaphores = waitSemas;
      shadowSubmit.pSignalSemaphores = shadowSignal;
      shadowSubmit.pWaitDstStageMask = waitFlags;
      // Submit shadow rendering.
      m_pRhi->GraphicsSubmit(shadowSubmit);

      offscreenSI.pWaitSemaphores = shadowSignal;
    }

    // Check if sky needs to update it's cubemap.
    if (m_pSky->NeedsRendering()) {
      skyboxSI.waitSemaphoreCount = 2;
      skyboxSI.pWaitSemaphores = skyWaits;
      offscreenSI.commandBufferCount = 2;
      offscreenSI.signalSemaphoreCount = 2;
      offscreenSI.pSignalSemaphores = skyWaits;
      offscreenSI.pCommandBuffers = skyBuffers;
      m_pSky->MarkClean();
    }

    // Offscreen PBR Forward Rendering Pass.
    m_pRhi->GraphicsSubmit(offscreenSI);

    // Render Sky onto our render textures.
    m_pRhi->GraphicsSubmit(skyboxSI);

    // High Dynamic Range and Gamma Pass.
    if (m_HDR._Enabled) m_pRhi->GraphicsSubmit(hdrSI);

    // Before calling this cmd buffer, we want to submit our offscreen buffer first, then
    // sent our signal to our swapchain cmd buffers.

    // TODO(): We want to hold off on signalling GraphicsFinished Semaphore, and instead 
    // have it signal the SignalUI semaphore instead. UI Overlay will be the one to use
    // GraphicsFinished Semaphore to signal end of frame rendering.
    VkSemaphore signal = m_pRhi->GraphicsFinishedSemaphore();
    VkSemaphore uiSig = m_pUI->Signal()->Handle();
    m_pRhi->SubmitCurrSwapchainCmdBuffer(1, &waitSemaphores, 1, &signal);

    // Render the Overlay.
    RenderOverlay();

  EndFrame();
```

On an Nvidia GTX 870M, the results seem to work as expected, [image: Nvidia result]

However, using Intel HD Graphics 620, I get this screenshot, unfortunately I can't display here because it's too big: https://github.com/CheezBoiger/Recluse-Game/blob/master/Regression/Shaders/ForwardPass.png

It seems as though the scene from previous frames are left un-cleared onto the color attachment, as if it was rendering onto a separate surface and using that instead, but it should be cleared every frame at the beginning of rendering...

Removing VK_LOAD_OP_LOAD and replacing with VK_LOAD_OP_CLEAR, the situation clears, however, only the skybox is rendered... I am wondering if my render pass is not doing something that it needs to be doing on Intel hardware, or am I going about drawing the skybox onto my rendered scene all wrong?

Much appreciated on the help.

*** Update *** 
**Problem fixed, with solution by @Ekzuzy below.**

Final Image on Intel Hardware after fix:
[image]

Comment: The link to the Intel result doesn't work for anyone else.

Comment: I'm still not clear on why you're using LOAD_OP_LOAD. It looks like you're doing that in the renderpass that draws *to* the skybox cubemap? Why would you want to reuse/modify the previous skybox rather than clearing the cubemap so you can draw a new skybox?

Comment: @JesseHall Oops, I wasn't very clear on that part. the renderpass using LOAD_OP_LOAD is used on the framebuffer that holds the drawn scene, so as to draw the (already rendered) skybox on top. I use another renderpass to draw onto the skybox whenever the sun direction changes. When the skybox needs to render, it will do so as you say, it will clear and draw the new skybox before using it on the scene. I didn't add that renderpass to the post for some reason, I'll update.

Comment: I'll also update the image that doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You always provide UNDEFINED layout for the initial layout in all Your render passes and for all attachments. Layout transition from UNDEFINED layout to any other layout doesn't guarantee image contents to be preserved. So if You create a render pass with LOAD value for the load op, You need to provide an actual layout given image has just before the render pass starts. This applies to other layout transitions as well (through memory barriers).

As for clears, some images should be cleared at the beginning of a frame or render pass. So for them You can leave UNDEFINED as the initial layout but You should change the load op to clear.

As to why this works on Nvidia and doesn't work on Intel - layout transitions don't have any effect on Nvidia's hardware, but they are important on Intel's platforms (and on AMD's too). So skipping (or setting improper) layout transitions, even though it violates the specification, it still should work on Nvidia. But don't do that just because it works. Such approach is invalid. And future platforms, even from the same vendor, may behave differently.

Comment: Amazing, I was totally not aware of this, as I presumed the image would be preserved, as if VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED should be used for anything pertaining to old image layouts. Maybe that's just Nvidia's magic that persuades me to believe that it "just works." This definitely fixed the problem. I also think I really need to read the vulkan specs a little more closely. Anyways, much appreciated @Ekzuzy! I'll update this post with the resulting image produced after the fix

Comment: @wubw Spec isn't so bad, but many informations about one topic are placed in various parts of the specification. Tutorials, though not as thorough and complete, are more succinct and easier to understand.

Comment: yes indeed, I think I've learned quite alot of vulkan from tutorials, notably from Alexander Overvoorde, Sasha Willems, at work, and even from your tutorials (Vulkan cookbook, API without secrets)! Of course, couldn't hurt to read the specs once in a while, but I do appreciate the amount of effort you guys put into making Vulkan less of a pain to learn, and more of an fun API to use :)

Comment: @wubw Wow, thanks for reading my book! I always hope it will prove useful for people and I still get positively shocked that it indeed might be useful as more and more people is reading it!! :-) If You have any other problems, just ask ;-).